# Azure ServiceBus ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync() Fails

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to implement the "message deferral" pattern in Azure ServiceBus and having trouble just getting a basic sample to work correctly. I'm using `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` v5.0.0 and following advice from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437666/how-to-defer-a-azure-service-bus-message) and [this Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral).

```
// Send a message
var sender = new MessageSender("my_sb_connection_string", "my_queue_name", RetryPolicy.Default);
await sender.SendAsync(new Message());

// Receive the message, defer it and then receive the deferred message
var receiver = new MessageReceiver("my_sb_connection_string", "my_queue_name", 
                                   ReceiveMode.PeekLock, RetryPolicy.Default);

var msg = await receiver.ReceiveAsync();

await receiver.DeferAsync(msg.SystemProperties.LockToken);

var deferredMsg = await receiver.ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync(msg.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber);
```

Every time I call `ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync()`, I get an exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageNotFoundException: Messages not found. One or more sequence numbers missing.
```

I'm sure there's something simple that I'm doing wrong, but I can't see what it might be.

Comment: Is the message with that specific sequence number in the queue?

Comment: @SeanFeldman The message is on the Dead Letter Queue immediately after the `DeferAsync()` call. That's not at all what I would expect.

Comment: @SeanFeldman So I created a second receiver for the Dead Letter Queue and tried to receive the deferred message there. No luck, I get `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageNotFoundException: Failed to lock one or more specified messages as they were not deferred messages.`

So the message isn't in the primary queue and you can't receive it from the DLQ. At least, not as a deferred message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that I had the queue's "Max Delivery Count" setting at 1 - the message was going into the DLQ (apparently) because it hit max delivery count.

Changing Max Delivery Count to a value greater than 1 allows the `DeferAsync() call to properly mark the message as deferred.

That seems like a bug to me. https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/375

Comment: This makes sense. Deferring a message means that it will be delivered a 2nd time. If you have set your queue to allow only 1 delivery, a message cannot be redelivered and thus cannot be deferred.

Comment: I consider it a bug, or a poor design choice. The whole point of deferring a message is to set it aside for processing that will take a while. So when you first defer a message, you haven't processed it yet; processing is understood to be ongoing in the background. Abandon/Complete has not been called, so the delivery attempt should remain at 1.  When you first receive a deferred message, you're just reacquiring your initial lock on it, so that should not count as a delivery attempt. When you subsequently Abandon an already-deferred message, that's when it should increment the delivery count.