# Deferring and re-receiving a deferred message in an IHostBuilder hosted service

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, message-queue, azureservicebus

If the processing of an Azure Service Bus message depends on another resource, e.g. an API or a database service, and this resource is not available, not calling `CompleteMessageAsync()` is not an option, because the message will be immediately received again until the Max Delivery Count is reached, and then put into the DLQ. If an API is down for maintenance, we want to wait a bit before retrying.

One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437666/how-to-defer-a-azure-service-bus-message) has the general steps for deferring and receiving deferred messages. This is a little better than Microsoft's documentation, but not enough for me to understand the intent of the API, and how it is to be implemented in a hosted service that basically sits in ServiceBusProcessor.StartProcessingAsync all day long.

This is the basic structure of my service:

```
public class ServiceBusWatcher : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        ReceiveMessagesAsync();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async void ReceiveMessagesAsync()
    {
        ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
        processor = client.CreateProcessor(queueName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());
        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
        await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
    }

    async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
         // a dependency is not available that allows me to process a message. so:
         await args.DeferMessageAsync(args.Message);
```

Once the message is deferred, it is my understanding that the processor will not get to it anymore (or will it?). Instead, I have to use ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync() to receive it, along with the sequence number of the originally received message.

In my case, it will make sense to wait minutes or hours before trying again.
This could be done with a separate service that uses a timer and an explicit call to `ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync()`, as opposed to using a ServiceBusProcessor. I also suppose that the deferred message sequence numbers will have to be persisted in non-volatile storage so that they don't get lost.

Does this sound like a viable approach? I don't like having to remember its sequence numbers so that I can get to a message later. It goes against everything that using a message queue brings to the table in the first place.

Or, instead of deferring, I could just post a new "internal" message with the sequence number and use the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property to delay receiving it. Once I receive this message, I could call `ReceiveDeferredMessageAsync()` with that sequence number to get to the original message. This seems elegant at the surface, but messages could quickly multiply if there is a longer outage of a dependency.

Another idea that could work without another service: I could complete and repost the payload of the message and set `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` to a time in the future, as described in another answer to [the question I mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437666/how-to-defer-a-azure-service-bus-message). Assuming that this works (Microsoft's documentation does not mention what this property is for), it seems simple and clean, and I like simple.

How have you solved this? Is there a better/preferred way that balances low complexity with high robustness without requiring a large amount of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferring a message works when you know what message you want to retrieve later and your receiver will have the message sequence number saved to retrieve the deferred message. If the receiver has no ability to save message sequence number, the *delaying* the message is a better option. Delaying a message will mean to copy the original message data into a newly scheduled one and completing the original message. That way the consumer doesn't have to neither hold on to the message sequence number nor initiate the retrieval of a specific message.

Comment: Thanks, I came to same conclusion. Hanging on to the sequence numbers means I have to build a shadow queue of sorts, defeating the purpose of using Service Bus.